# No Nvidia "On-Demand" option in Elementary OS?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-driver

I just installed Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera. I've been using Ubuntu before this and I had my Nvidia profile set as "On-Demand" to reduce power usage and save battery life. I prefer using the GPU only when I want it.

In Elementary OS I noticed that there is no "On-Demand" profile available.

So why is that? I'm probably missing some information about how Elementary OS installs Nvidia Drivers by default compared to Ubuntu when installing the distro.

Also, is it possible to get the "On-Demand" profile?

EDIT: Just to make it clear. I did not manually install the nvidia-drivers. It was installed automatically when I installed the OS.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but the 'on demnad' profile was available in Ubuntu starting with 19.10, and since elemenatry OS 5 is based on 18.04... elementary OS 6 might suport it though, if devs decide to add a way of launching apps using the dedicated GPU, like Gnome's right click menu option "Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card")

Comment: @Vlad oh that would make sense then.  thanks for clarifying :D